# How do I create a hierarchy between my sharepoint pages?

Tags: sharepoint-online

So I have a bunch of pages already created on my site but I don't know how to go about giving them an actual hierarchy.  Visually in the navigation bar there is a hierarchy but my breadcrumb links do not act like there is a hierarchy.  I am using a bootstrap theme from BindTuning and the bottom breadcrumb links only ever show "home page" > "Pages" > "current page"

So the start and end is correct but the middle only ever says pages since that is where the page files are stored in share point.  Sometimes there should even be another level of navigation in between that and it should never say "pages" in the breadcrumbs.

How can I go about making a hierarchy between the pages I have made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pages aren't "hierarchical", but folders are! Also, sites are like folders, so you can think of them the same in this context.

To display a breadcrumb automatically you need a hierarchical structure, OR you need a mapping for each item (Page) that shows what it's parent is.

So you could use folders/sites to create a hierarchy automatically, which would then need to be read by your breadcrumb code (potentially customized). Or you could map each page to it's parent with a custom property, and adjust the breadcrumb code to take this property into account.

Answer (score 0):

If your using a Wiki Library you can easily add links to any page by using the double brackets [[page name]]. You could establish your hierarchy on the pages that way but it would be a manual process. All pages simply sit in the root folder of that library so regardless of how many pages you create they will never have any actual hierarchy.